# TypeError: options is undefined (customer-data.js)

Tags: magento2, error

I'm building a custom Magento theme that relies on a couple of third party JS libraries (slick, bootstrap) and I've suddenly hit a problem that I cannot figure out.
When on the homepage I receive the error:

```
TypeError: options is undefined
```

In the customer-data.js file on line 85:

```
return $.getJSON(options.sectionLoadUrl, parameters).fail(function (jqXHR) {
```

This only happens on the homepage and any other page such as search results I do not receive this error, this leads me to believe it is the cause of some third party js on the homepage conflicting.

The shopping cart and Bootstrap.js stop working due to this error but slick slider continues to work fine. I've tried removing all code related to Slick and temporarily removed it from the RequireJS-Config file however this didn't change anything :(

Here's a link to the site in progress: **removed**

If anybody has had any experience with this any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resolution for me was removing the following line:

```
<referenceBlock name="content" display="false"/>
```

I put this in to hide the CMS content of the page however it caused the following script:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">{"*":{"Magento_Customer\/js\/customer-data":{"sectionLoadUrl":"http:\/\/magento-2-1-4.dev\/customer\/section\/load\/","cookieLifeTime":"3600","updateSessionUrl":"http:\/\/magento-2-1-4.dev\/customer\/account\/updateSession\/"}}}</script>
```

To not load, thus causing the error. I guess i'll find another method to hide CMS content

Answer (score 3):

After debug I found that in default magento inside the `options` variable object with next data:

[image: debug data default magento]

On your site the `options` object is `undefined`:

[image: debug data on site]

I think the problem comes from the block:

```
<block name="customer.customer.data"
    class="Magento\Customer\Block\CustomerData"
    template="Magento_Customer::js/customer-data.phtml"/>
```

defined in the `default.xml` layout (default magento):

> magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

I think this block was removed from the layout of your home page. You should add it, because the customer data is an important part of the Magento functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work as of yet, but thank you for the screenshots, it's given me a better idea of the problem and how to further debug any issues :) I'll report back with any findings. Thanks once again

Comment: Life saver, been causing me issues this!