# Uncaught Error [object Object] at Object. (customer-data.js:86)

Tags: magento-2.1

I am seeing the following error in the console on every page of our site (Magento 2.1.4)...

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () - customer/section/load/?sections=review&update_section_id=false&_=1507203330016
Uncaught Error: [object Object]
at Object.<anonymous> (customer-data.js:86)
at fire (jquery.js:3099)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3211)
at done (jquery.js:9312)
at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:9720)
```

It only seems to appear when I merge the JS in admin. If JS is not merged then the error does not appear.

Does anyone know what this is related to (other than the merge of JS)?

I checked this answer: [TypeError: options is undefined (customer-data.js)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176659/typeerror-options-is-undefined-customer-data-js) but I have not extended Magento_Customer module so I dont think it is related.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more in-depth explanation...

`Magento\Customer\Controller\Section\Load` returns a 400 status code when the requested section is not found within `Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface::sectionSourceMap`

Source maps are added by their respective modules' using dependency injection in `module/etc/frontend/di.xml`. The `review` section is added here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9db4501d29028ba9ac552f14d80b42bc923847f4/app/code/Magento/Review/etc/frontend/di.xml#L32

I've found this information helpful when troubleshooting other customer section request errors.

Comment: Great info thank you

Answer (score 0):

Although [TypeError: options is undefined (customer-data.js)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176659/typeerror-options-is-undefined-customer-data-js) was not the answer it did help me to debug - turns out my reviews module was disabled - re-enabling solved it