# Dependecy error Magento 2 ('sectionLoadUrl' error)

Tags: magento2, module, requirejs, dependency, magento2.2.3

I've asked a similar question before, but because of some research, it would not have been relevant anymore. So here a more comprehensive explanation of my problem.

**My scenario**

I want the cart page to update without a refresh when the quantity has been changed of a product in the order list.

**What I did**

First of all, and most essential in this whole problem: **I reinstalled Magento** so there was a clean work environment I could test the module in. 
Secondly, I created a module, named `AjaxCart`. This module consists of the following files:

[image: Directory breakdown]

`module.xml` has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_AjaxCart" setup_version="2.0.0"/>
</config>
```

`checkout_cart_index.xml` has the following content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Vendor_AjaxCart/js/jquery.cartAjaxQty.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

`requirejs-config.js` has the following content:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            ajaxQty: 'Vendor_AjaxCart/js/jquery.cartAjaxQty'
        }
    }
};
```

and finally `jquery.cartAjax.js` has the following content:

```
    require(['jquery', 'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals'], function () {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($, getTotalsAction){
        $(".cart-container .form-cart .action.update").remove();
        // On change handler
        jQuery(document).on('change', 'input[name$="[qty]"]', function(){
                    console.log("quantity changed");
                    var form = jQuery(jQuery(this).closest('form'));

                    $.ajax({
                        url: form.attr('action'),
                        data: form.serialize(),
                        showLoader: true,
                        context: this.changedInput,
                        success: function (res) {
                            var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res);
                            var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate");
                            $("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);
                            var deferred = $.Deferred();
                            getTotalsAction([], deferred);
                            console.log('Ajax succes function completed');
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                            console.log(err.Message);
                        }
                    });

                }
            );
    });
});
```

So, I also know where things go wrong: *the requirements*.
If the file only has the following requirement:

```
require([
    'jquery']
```

There is nothing wrong, and I can `console.log` the changes in quantities.

**Problem**

If I add the requirement I have in the file (which I need to update the cart summary block), I get the following error on the cart page:

[image: sectionloadurl error]

I don't know if this is a Magento 2.2.x bug, or is it because of the file or directory structures I have made. Anyhow, it is something that has me in it's grip for a long time and I am really thinking this is just a problem caused by Magento self and not my code.

I'm really curious if someone could try exactly what I did (except the clean install, a little bit too much to ask) and see if he/she gets the same problem or if someone knows an answer to this. I've also tried changing themes, but no luck.

***-- ADITIONAL INFO --***

I've tried to perform a change on the cart in Firefox, but upon showing the page (like in Chrome), Firefox also throws an error, but this time a different one:

[image: options is not defined]

So I've followed this question:

[TypeError: options is undefined (customer-data.js)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176659/typeerror-options-is-undefined-customer-data-js)

But no luck.

***-- Update --***

As [Pascal Wientjes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/222502/63644) pointed out, I should use `define` instead of `require`. I did this, and than the following error occured:

[image: Define error]

This could be fixed by changing the `requirejs-config.js` file to:

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        ajaxQty: 'Vendor_AjaxCart/js/cartAjaxQty'
    }
},

deps: [
    "Vendor/js/cartAjaxQty"
]
```

};

And stop including the `jquery.cartAjax.js` in the head of `checkout_cart_index.xml`. But unfortunately, the old error shows up again.

If of any use: when included using above way, the file is loaded on every page of course. For example, when browsing to the home page, the following errors also show up, but this is probably because of the information it is missing on those pages (just providing as much information as possible):

[image: storecode and quotedata error]

-- Update --

Sometimes, really sometimes, the page somehow loads correctly, even while customer-data.js is loaded AFTER cartAjaxQty.js. You can see I have a `console.log("running");` inside my code which is printend in the console:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to add the section `Magento_Checkout` to your `module.xml`? It is mandatory to use section because of module loading order it may cause some dependency issues. Run a `bin/magento setup:upgrade` to reorganise your `app/etc/config.php` file and so the loading order.

Comment: This question may help - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160707/cannot-read-property-section-loadurl-of-undefined

Comment: @MatthéoGeoffray Okay, I did. `Module_AjaxCart` is above in the list, above `Magento_Checkout`. This means `Module_AjaxCart` is being loaded before `Magento_Checkout`? And that can cause the error?

Comment: @BenCrook I've already tried that and did not help unfortunately

Comment: @MatthéoGeoffray I've set the sequence like so: 

`<module name="Module_AjaxCart" setup_version="2.0.0">
  <sequence>
   <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
  </sequence>
 </module>` and loads the Checkout before Module_AjaxCart but changes nothing unfortunately.

Comment: @bramulous OK that was only a lead. In any case you have to add it so that is not a bad things ;)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip! Really curious what else it could be :-|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it eventually, with help and thinking of [Pascal Wientjes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/46026/pascal-wientjes)

So, when discussing about what the issue could be with said person, we came to the conclusion that `customer-data.js` was loaded after `cartAjaxQty.js`.

Even though I included the `Magento_Customer` module in a sequence-tag within the `module.xml`, still `customer-data.js` still got loaded AFTER my script. I posted a question about this:

[<sequence> not working?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223612/sequence-not-working/223778#223778)

Where other people reacted, and so Magento loads `customer-data.js` via it's layout. So I had to figure out another way. Pascal told maybe you could use a `$(document).ready`, so I tried but no luck. I thought.

This eventually fixed it: `$(window).on("load", function ()`

My `script.phtml` eventually looks like this!

```
<script>
require ([
        'jquery'
    ],
function ($) {
    $(window).on("load", function () {
        require([
            'Vendor_AjaxCart/js/cartAjaxQty'
        ]);
    });
});
```

And now all loads fine. It's not the fix I had hoped for, a more cleaner approach would've been my preference but it fixes my error.

Comment: I still don't get it why normal require won't work. But if it works then it works I guess .

Comment: My neither. That is what makes it frustrating. Maybe because sduif said here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223612/sequence-not-working/223778#223778 , that it is due to the fact that customer-data.js gets included by the default.xml ..

Answer (score 4):

You should use define in your jquery.cartAjax.js file instead of require,
also pass $ as an argument so you can use it in the ajax call, require is specifically designed for phtml files and define for javascript files.

```
define([
       'jquery',
       'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals'
       ], function ($, getTotalsAction) {

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cart-container .form-cart .action.update").remove();
    // On change handler
    jQuery(document).on('change', 'input[name$="[qty]"]', function(){
                console.log("quantity changed");
                var form = jQuery(jQuery(this).closest('form'));

                $.ajax({
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    showLoader: true,
                    context: this.changedInput,
                    success: function (res) {
                        var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res);
                        var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate");
                        $("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);
                        var deferred = $.Deferred();
                        getTotalsAction([], deferred);
                        console.log('Ajax succes function completed');
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                        console.log(err.Message);
                    }
                });

            }
        );
    });
});
```

hope it helpes

Update:

i think there's also somehting going wrong with the call to the file

it should look somehting like this:
`<script>require(['ajaxQty']);</script>` where ajaxQty is the name declared in the `require-config.js`

Comment: I've tried this before, and unfortunately it throws: `Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ($, getTotalsAction)`

Comment: I figured this is due to the fact that I load it in whilst using `<script src="Module_AjaxCart/js/cartAjaxQty.js" />` to include it on the page within my `checkout_cart_index.xml`. When I use `deps` inside my require-js.config, the file won't throw above error anymore but than goes back to the old error..

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: You mean like `<script>require(['ajaxQty']);</script>` to be included within the `<head>`-tag in `checkout_cart_index.xml` ? Because the script tag needs a `src` and can't have character content.

Comment: no no just anywhere in a phtml file, don't try to do anything in the head.. let require do all the work :p

Comment: Okay, I've added it within a .pthml file. With `deps` included in requirejs-config, I still get the error, without `deps` too and it even prints the error two times then hehe.

Comment: i think these errors might be completely unrelated to your javascript dependancy's it seems that for some reason there might not be a problem in your javascript dependancy's but more likely that something is removing the main `content` container from your cart page, more info here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8628

Comment: Unfortunately, I have used a clean install, used both the blank and luma theme, added the .xml code in the link provided and still the error occurs. I get really desperate right now haha

Comment: your error all seem to be related to a script (not neceserally yours) not being able to access the `customer-data`. might also be a possibility that that script is fired before the snippet that builds the customer-data. have you tried commenting out all the `getTotals` out of your script and see what happens?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76204/discussion-between-bramulous-and-pascal-wientjes).

Comment: "require is specifically designed for phtml files and define for javascript files." - This is not true, require JS was not built for Magento and has no understanding of PHTML files.

General rule of thumb is you use define when you want to define a module that will be reused by your application and you use require to simply load a dependency. Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366073/requirejs-define-vs-require