# Magento TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.2.4

```
main.js:37 TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined
at quote.js:33
```

This error is appearing in the browser console and is happening on several pages. Mainly on the registration page. The error is preventing masks from being applied to fields.

**What i tried:**

[Based on this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220206/dependecy-error-magento-2-sectionloadurl-error), I tried to add "domReady!" in the define section, but it didn't work.

I also tried to add $(document).ready(function() into the file, although it fixed, several other errors started appearing in Checkout, from other files that depend on quote.js.

Comment: do you have any custom extensions installed?

Comment: Check in your quote.js "quoteData" var is define or not.

Comment: Try to disable all third party extension, then enable one by one and check from which this error comes.